# Magento 2 - Set 2 prices on product view

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to work with 2 prices in the product view page.
I need the regular price and another price with a percentage discount.
The idea is show to customer how much he will pay when choosing a specific payment method. 
For example:
Regular price: 280.00 - Pay on delivery: 275.50

I've created the module where we can set on dashboard how much will be the discount. but, I can't find out how to load both.

Answer (score 0):

You can set price per website basis.
You need to go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope.
Then in the tab ""Price"", set price scope to ""Website"" instead of global.
Different price for store view, many extension available. Here is some example:
https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-multiple-store-view-pricing-extension.html

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer. but, the point here is not have different prices for each store. is having different prices for payment method. I can set that as a rule and the price will be showing on checkout with the discount. BUT, customer needs to know what's going to be the price with discount and with no discount on product view page.

Comment: Hi. For your problem, to display different prices on multiple stores you need an extra extension to be able to do this (you can refer to the link we sent in the previous answer. ), this extension can allow you to configure prices across multiple stores.